# No error message prompt but code cannot work

Tags: javascript, android, html, phonegap-desktop-app

I have created my first android apps with *Phonegap Desktop App*. Edited the index.html using Notepad++ and here is my javascript code:

The apps can run in both mobile phonegap and desktop browser, but all the database functions are not running. Please help~

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>  
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=2">  
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.2/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.min.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.2/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function()
{
document.addEventListener("deviceready", MobileReady, false);
var dbase = window.openDatabase("Database", "1.0", "MyEventsdatab", 200000);

function MobileReady()
{
    alert("Welcome");
    dbase.transaction(pDB, errDB, sucDB);
    document.addEventListener('backbutton', onBack, false);
}

function onBack()
{
    if($.mobile.activePage.is('#page1'))
    {
        navigator.app.exitApp();
    }
    else
    {
        db.transaction(qDB, errDB);
    }
}

function pDB(x)
{
    x.executeSql('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Event (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, eventname TEXT NOT NULL, eventlocation TEXT, eventdate DATE, starttime TIME, eventorganizer TEXT)\
                ');
    x.executeSql('SELECT id, eventname, eventlocation FROM Event ORDER BY eventname', [], qSuccess, errDB);
}

function qDB(x)
{
    x.executeSql('SELECT id, eventname, eventlocation FROM Event ORDER BY eventname', [], qSuccess, errDB);
}

function sucDB()
{
    dbase.transaction(qDB, errDB);
}

function qSuccess(x, results)
{
    $.mobile.showPageLoadingMsg(true);
    var len = results.rows.length;
    $("#userList").html('');
    for (var i=0; i<len; i++)
    {
        var row= results.rows.item(i);
        var hdata = '<li id="'+row["id"]+'"><a href="#"><h2>'+row["name"]+'</h2></a></li>';
        $("#userList").append(hdata).listview('refresh');
    }
    $.mobile.changePage($("#page1"), { transition : "slide"});
    $.mobile.hidePageLoadingMsg();
}

function errDB(err)
{
    alert("Fail Database");
}

$("#page3 .error").html('').hide();

$(".addNew").bind("click", function (F)
{
    $("#page3 .error").html('').hide();
    $.mobile.changePage ($("#page3"), { transition : "slide", reverse : true });
    $("#addNewPageHeader").html("Add New Event");
});

$("#save").bind("click", function (F)
{
    var eventname = $.trim($("#eventname").val()));
    var eventlocation = $.trim($("#eventlocation").val()));
    var eventdate = $.trim($("#eventdate").val());
    var starttime = $.trim($("#starttime").val());
    var eventorganizer = $.trim($("#eventorganizer").val());
    console.log(eventname+' '+eventlocation+' '+eventdate+' '+starttime+' '+eventorganizer);
    if (eventnamename == '')
    {
        $("#page3 .error").html('Please enter event name.').show();
    }
    else
    {
        formReset();
        var id = $("#id").val();
        $("#id").val('');
        if (id == '')
        { 
            dbase.transaction(function (x){ x.executeSql("INSERT INTO Event (eventname, eventlocation, eventdate, starttime, eventorganizer) VALUES  (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)",[eventname, eventlocation, eventdate, starttime, eventorganizer],
            qDB, errDB); });
        }
        else
        {   
            dbase.transaction(function (x){ x.executeSql("UPDATE Event SET eventname=?, eventlocation=?, eventdate=?, starttime=?, eventorganizer=? WHERE id=? ",[eventname, eventlocation, eventdate, starttime, eventorganizer, id],
            qDB, errDB); });
        }
        dbase.transaction(qDB, errDB);
    }
});

$(".refresh").bind("click", function (F)
{
    dbase.transaction(qDB, errDB);
});

$(".back").bind("click", function (F)
{
    formReset();
    dbase.transaction(qDB, errDB);
});

function formReset()
{
    $("#page3 .error").html('').hide();
    $("#page3 #eventname").val('');
    $("#page3 #eventlocation").val('');
    $("#page3 #eventdate").val('');
    $("#page3 #starttime").val('');
    $("#page3 #eventorganizer").val('');
    $("#page3 #addNewPageHeader").html('');
}

$("#page1 [data-role='content'] ul").on('tap taphold', 'li', function (F)
{
    F.preventDefault();
    F.stopImmediatePropagation();
    var liId = this.id;
    if (F.type === 'taphold')
    {
        navigator.notification.vibrate(30);
        var $popup = $('#actionList-popup');
        $("#actionList").html('');
        $("#actionList").append('<li id="editEvent&'+Id+'">Update</li>').listview('refresh');
        $("#actionList").append('<li id="deleteEvent&'+Id+'">Delete</li>').listview('refresh');
        $popup.popup();
        $popup.popup('open');
        $("#tapHoldCheck").val('true');
    }
    else if (F.type === 'tap')
    {
        if ($("#tapHoldCheck").val() == '')
        {   //tap will only work if the value of textbox is blank
            dbase.transaction(function (x)
            {
                x.executeSql("SELECT eventname, eventlocation, eventdate, starttime, eventorganizer  FROM Event WHERE id=?;", [liId], function (x, results)
                {
                    var row = results.rows.item(0);
                    $.mobile.showPageLoadingMsg(true);
                    $.mobile.changePage($("#page2"), { transition : "slide"});
                    $("#headerName").html(row['eventname']);
                    $("#eventname").html(row['eventname']);
                    $("#eventlocation").html(row['eventlocation']);
                    $("#eventdate").html(row['date']);
                    $("#starttime").html(row['starttime']);
                    $("#eventorganizer").html(row['eventorganizer']);
                    $('#eventView').trigger('create');
                    $('#eventView').listview('refresh');
                    $.mobile.hidePageLoadingMsg();
                });
            });
        }
    }
});

//Change the hidden field value when the popup is closed
$('#actionList-popup').bind({
    popupafterclose: function(F)
    {
        $("#tapHoldCheck").val('');
    }
});

$("#page1 [data-role='popup'] ul").on('click', 'li', function (F)
{
    var action_liId = this.id.split('&');
    var action = action_liId[0];
    var id = action_liId[1];
    if (action == 'editEvent')
    {
        dbase.transaction(function (x)
        {
            x.executeSql("SELECT eventname, eventlocation, eventdate, starttime, eventorganizer  FROM Evt WHERE id=?;", [id], function (x)
            {
                var row = results.rows.item(0);
                $("#eventname").val(row['eventname']);
                $("#eventlocation").val(row['eventlocation']);
                $("#eventdate").val(row['eventdate']);
                $("#starttime").val(row['starttime']);
                $("#eventorganizer").val(row['eventorganizer']);
                $("#id").val(id);
                $("#addNewPageHeader").html('Update');
                $.mobile.changePage ($("#page3"), { transition : "slide", reverse : true });
            });
        });
    }
    if (action == 'deleteEvent')
    {
        navigator.notification.confirm(
        'Delete Event!?',
        function(Button){deleteConfirm(Button, id);},
        'Delete Event',
        'Confirm, Cancel'
        );
    }
});

function deleteConfirm(Button, id)
{
    if (Button === 1)
    {
        dbase.transaction(function (x){ x.executeSql("DELETE FROM Event WHERE id=?", [id], qDB, errDB); });
    }
    if (Button === 2)
    {
        $.mobile.changePage($("#page1"), { transition : "slide"});
    }
}
});

</script>
</head>
```

This is the form i created:

```
<body>

<!-- Index Page Start -->
<div data-role="page" id="page1">
<div data-role="header" data-position="fixed">
<a href="#page3" class="addNew" data-role="button" data-icon="add" data-theme="b" title="Add New">Add New</a>
    <h1>List Of Event</h1>
</div>
<div data-role="content">
    <ul data-role="listview" data-filter="true" data-filter-placeholder="Search Event..." id="userList">  </ul>
</div>
<div data-role="popup" id="actionList-popup" data-overlay-theme="a">
    <ul data-role="listview" id="actionList" style="border: 1px solid blue; width:15em">  </ul>
</div>
<input type="hidden" id="tapHoldCheck" value="" />
</div>
<!-- Index Page End -->

<!-- Data Display Page Start -->
<div data-role="page" id="page2">
<div data-role="header" data-position="fixed">
    <a href="#page1" class="back" data-role="button" data-icon="arrow-l" data-theme="b" title="Back">Home</a>
    <h1 id="headerName"></h1>   
</div>
<div data-role="content">
    <ul data-role="listview" id="eventView">
        <li>Event Name: <span id="eventname"></span></li>
        <li>Event Location: <span id="eventlocation"></span></li>
        <li>Event Date: <span id="eventdate"></span></li>
        <li>Event Start Time: <span id="starttime"></span></li>
        <li>Event Organizer: <span id="eventorganizer"></span></li>
    </ul>
</div>
</div>
<!-- Data Display Page End -->

<!-- Form Page Start -->
<div data-role="page" id="page3">
<div data-role="header" data-position="fixed">
    <a href="#page1" class="back" data-role="button" data-icon="arrow-l" data-theme="a" title="Back">Home</a>
    <h1 id="addNewPageHeader"></h1>
    <a href="#page1" id="save" data-role="button" data-icon="check" data-theme="a" title="Save">Save</a>
</div>
<div data-role="content">
    <div class='error'></div>
    <div data-role="fieldcontain">
        <label for="eventname">Event Name:</label>
        <input type="text" name="eventname" id="eventname" required="true"  value=""></input>
    </div>
    <div data-role="fieldcontain">
        <label for="eventlocation">Event Location:</label>
        <input type="text" name="eventlocation" id="eventlocation"  value=""  ></input>
    </div>

    <div data-role="fieldcontain">
        <label for="eventdate">Event Date:</label>
        <input type="date" name="eventdate" id="eventdate"  value=""></input>
    </div>
    <div data-role="fieldcontain">
        <label for="starttime">Event Start Time:</label>
        <input type="time" name="starttime" id="starttime" value=""></input>
    </div>
    <div data-role="fieldcontain">
        <label for="eventorganizer">Event Organizer:</label>
        <input type="text" name="eventorganizer" id="eventorganizer" value=""></input>
    </div>
    <input type="hidden" name="id" id="id" value="" />
</div>
</div>  
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please **answer the following questions in your post**. Since this appears to be your first post on this subject. Is this your first hybrid App?
Are you using the *Phonegap Desktop App*? Are you using [CLI, SDK or Build](https://github.com/jessemonroy650/top-phonegap-mistakes/blob/master/new-to-Phonegap.md#001) ? Please do not assume the answer, please read the link. Once you have answer the question *in the post*, respond in the comments so I know you have added information to the post.

Comment: @JesseMonroy650 Yes. first hybrid app. I'm using Phonegap Desktop. The application is downloaded from here: http://docs.phonegap.com/getting-started/1-install-phonegap/desktop/#win

Comment: You have several mistakes. I am going to list all the mistakes in the answer. Do you have any other questions before I answer?

Comment: @JesseMonroy650 Owh thanks. 1 more question: is the jquery mobile version (script src=...) vary for different model of mobile? URL: https://jquerymobile.com/download/
because i need to change the version when im testing the app using different handphone.

Comment: hmmm.. This is where you will have a problem. Once you have finish development, it is best practice to have the javascript on the device - NOT on the internet. **To answer your question** all versions are stable and the same - whether the download or CDN. NOTE: The largest purpose of JQuery was developers did not have to worry about different hardware or browser. So (in theory) there should be no reason to change JQuery versions.

Comment: @JesseMonroy650 now i got clear on the jquery. thanks alot.
But then, please do warn and teach me to rectify the mistakes in my code. This is my first time on android app.

Answer (score 0):

WebSql database has been implemented by Chrome and few other browsers. You must be using browser which doesn't have support for WebSql. Try running the app in Chrome browsers. It has support for WebSql database.